# How to add toolbar to BokehJS plot?

Tags: javascript, bokeh

My goal is to add a toolbar to a BokehJS plot. According to the [plot tools documention](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#specifying-tools) this should be possible by doing (translating the Python example to Javascript):

```
plot.add_tools(new Bokeh.BoxZoomTool());
plot.add_tools(new Bokeh.ResetTool());
plot.toolbar_location = "right";
```

I have added these lines to the [basic BokehJS example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html#low-level-models) from the documentation, and they don't produce errors/warnings. However, the toolbar does not show up (properly) and the tools don't really seem to work.

I have prepared a minimal [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bluenote10/jd8akxdb/1/) to demonstrate the problem: When using the rectangle select tool the plot moves around strangely, which uncovers an unstyled version of the toolbar rendered underneath the plot.

So the question is how can I get a properly working toolbar in BokehJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add **bk-root** to the root element. `<div id="plot" class="mybokehplot bk-root"></div>`
2. Add corresponding css files (bokeh-0.12.0.min.css and bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.css).

JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/blackmiaool/xzvgrqLj/

Snippet here:

```js
// create some data and a ColumnDataSource
var x = Bokeh.LinAlg.linspace(-0.5, 20.5, 10);
var y = x.map(function(v) {
  return v * 0.5 + 3.0;
});
var source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
  data: {
    x: x,
    y: y
  }
});

// create some ranges for the plot
var xdr = new Bokeh.Range1d({
  start: -0.5,
  end: 20.5
});
var ydr = Bokeh.Range1d(-0.5, 20.5);

// make the plot
var plot = new Bokeh.Plot({
  title: "BokehJS Plot",
  x_range: xdr,
  y_range: ydr,
  plot_width: 400,
  plot_height: 400,
  background_fill_color: "#F2F2F7"
});

// add axes to the plot
var xaxis = new Bokeh.LinearAxis({
  axis_line_color: null
});
var yaxis = new Bokeh.LinearAxis({
  axis_line_color: null
});
plot.add_layout(xaxis, "below");
plot.add_layout(yaxis, "left");

// add grids to the plot
var xgrid = new Bokeh.Grid({
  ticker: xaxis.ticker,
  dimension: 0
});
var ygrid = new Bokeh.Grid({
  ticker: yaxis.ticker,
  dimension: 1
});
plot.add_layout(xgrid);
plot.add_layout(ygrid);

// add a Line glyph
var line = new Bokeh.Line({
  x: {
    field: "x"
  },
  y: {
    field: "y"
  },
  line_color: "#666699",
  line_width: 2
});
plot.add_glyph(line, source);

// now add the tools
plot.add_tools(new Bokeh.BoxZoomTool());
plot.add_tools(new Bokeh.ResetTool());
plot.toolbar_location = "right";

// add the plot to a document and display it
var doc = new Bokeh.Document();
doc.add_root(plot);
var div = document.getElementById("plot");
Bokeh.embed.add_document_standalone(doc, div);
```

```css
.mybokehplot {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.0.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.0.min.css">





<div id="plot" class="mybokehplot bk-root"></div>
```

[image]

P.S. I found that the edition of bokeh's css files and js files must be same, or you would get lots of bugs.